# Evaluating a passed object in a directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm making a custom directive for a textbox directive, which is part of a separate project.

```
<textbox restrict="{type: 'ref', callback: _.noop}"></textbox>
```

Note that I used noop for testing purposes at the moment. When I access:attrs.restrict in my directive, I see:

```
"{type: 'ref', callback: _.noop}"
```

I tried doing a $parse and a scope.$eval on this string to turn it into an object, but there's issues with callback being undefined.

How can I transform this string to an object correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular.FromJSON function

```
var jsonObject = angular.fromJson(jsonString)
```

$parse is a bit heavy compared to above. If you are sure you have a JSON string I won't suggest using $parse.

$scope.eval will internally call $parse

Comment: It's not JSON because there's a function wrapped inside of the object.